# How to write a template resulting in a primitive type?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a small fixed point arithmetic class with template parameters for the integer and fractional bits. When multiplying two small fixed point types the result is supposed to be a bigger fixed point type to capture the full result. E.g. multiplying two 8.8 fixed point numbers results in a 16.16 fixed point number.

My class looks like this:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int bits, unsigned int frac>
class FixedPoint {
  public:
    constexpr FixedPoint(int x = 0) : raw_(x << frac) { }
    constexpr FixedPoint(double x) : raw_(x * (T(1) << frac)) { }
  private:
    T raw_;
}
```

Now the problem is the **T** template parameter, especially for the multiplication as the result type differs from the argument types and can not be infered. Writing **a * b** does not work.

What I would like to do is to replace the **T** with a template type **Int<bits + frac>** that is an int8_t, int16_t, int32_t or int64_t depending on the number of bits total required.

How do I write such a type? I'm fine with limiting it to exactly 8, 16, 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Why are you exposing `T` at all to the user? Isn't that a hidden implementation detail? Shouldn't they only be able to see `bits` and `frac`?

Comment: Yes they should. I just didn't know how to pick the right type for T internally. That's basically the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest (and hence best) is to use an alias

```
template<std::size_t bits>
using integer_with_bits =
  conditional_t<(bits<= 8), std::int8_t,
  conditional_t<(bits<=16), std::int16_t,
  conditional_t<(bits<=32), std::int32_t,
  enable_if_t  <(bits<=64), std::int64_t> > > >;
```

which is the compile-time equivalent to the run-time `?:?:?:?:` cascade. Then `integer_with_bits<3>` is `int8_t`, while `integer_with_bits<65>` (and larger) create a compile-time error. In the above I used the auxiliaries

```
template<bool C, typename T>
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<C,T>::type;

template<bool C, typename T1, typename T2>
using conditional_t = typename std::conditional<C,T1,T2>::type;
```

Comment: The auxiliaries are going to be added to `std` if they aren't there already, so check your `std` to see if they are there.

Answer (score 3):

You may use template and specialization:

```
template <std::size_t N> struct sizedType;

template <> struct sizedType<8>  { using type = std::uint8_t; };
template <> struct sizedType<16> { using type = std::uint16_t; };
template <> struct sizedType<32> { using type = std::uint32_t; };
template <> struct sizedType<64> { using type = std::uint64_t; };
```

Comment: In case it's not clear - use `typename sizedType<bits+frac>::type` instead of `T`.

Answer (score 2):

This does not limit it to exactly the bits required.  Instead, it finds the smallest one that will fit that many bits:

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<size_t bits_at_least>
struct int_helper : int_helper<bits_at_least+1> {};

template<> struct int_helper<8  > : tag<int8_t > {};
template<> struct int_helper<16 > : tag<int16_t> {};
template<> struct int_helper<32 > : tag<int32_t> {};
template<> struct int_helper<64 > : tag<int64_t> {};
template<> struct int_helper<128> {}; // unsupported

template<std::size_t bits>
using integer = typename int_helper<bits>::type;
```

then `integer<3>` is `int8_t`.

`integer<65>` through `integer<128>` is a SFINAE error (nice and clean), and `integer<129>` is an error that will spam error messages at you (as it tries to instantiate an infinite cascade of recursive templates).

We can make this compile faster and generate better errors by removing that up to 63 recursive instantiations and doing bit fiddling instead.

```
template<size_t n>
using size = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, n>;

template<size_t n>
struct bits : size<bits<n/2>{}+1 > {};
template<>
struct bits<0> : size<0> {};

template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};

template<size_t bits_of_bits>
struct int_helper_2 {};

// optional 0 bits of bits uses char:
template<> struct int_helper_2<0> : tag<int8_t > {};
template<> struct int_helper_2<1> : tag<int8_t > {};
template<> struct int_helper_2<2> : tag<int8_t > {};
template<> struct int_helper_2<3> : tag<int8_t > {};
template<> struct int_helper_2<4> : tag<int16_t> {};
template<> struct int_helper_2<5> : tag<int32_t> {};
template<> struct int_helper_2<6> : tag<int64_t> {};

template<size_t bits_needed>
struct int_helper : int_helper_2< bits<bits_needed>{} > {};

template<size_t bits_needed>
using integer<bits_needed>=typename int_helper<bits_needed>::type;
```

which gives nice SFINAE errors at all sizes, and should compile faster (less type recursion).